# How to override some of java.sql.connection methods like prepareStatement createStatement or prepareCall?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to override some of the methods in connection interface to close preparedStatements and resultsSets when commit on the connection object gets called. There is a lot of resource-leak in my codebase and as a failsafe I wanted to implement this solution, where at every commit, I could look for all open statements and resultsets and close them.

In this case however, I don't have a class to override and call super() on all other methods. The object returned as a connection is a dynamic proxy - com.sun.proxy.$Proxy. Not sure of how to have my own methods called for this object. Any lead is highly appreciated.

PS: I am using an ojdbc8 jar in the project, which was recently upgraded from ojdbc7. To the best of my knowledge, we never came across any resource leakage issues (like maximum open cursors exceeded) in the previous version.

Comment: Why not just call close on the connection after you are done with it? I recommend using a try-with-resources or try-finally block.

Comment: @user506069 Thanks for the suggestion. I am doing that at most places I could find an issue - turning to try-with-resource. However, it is a very huge code repository and I wanted to be sure even if I couldn't identify a resource leak at some places. Also wanted to make sure that going forward any future code does not cause resource leaks.

Comment: A correctly implemented JDBC driver will already close results sets on commit (unless you're using holdable result sets). I'd suggest using a connection pool library that properly closes resources for you when the connection is returned to the pool.

Comment: You could code your own class implementing Connection to act as a facade in front of the third party Connection object. Add any custom logic you like to the facade class after it makes the call to the library class. Then refactor the code to use your facade class instead of accessing the existing connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your JDBC library open source? Then download the sources of the JDBC version, make this one code change, generate JAR again and use that instead. When you do this, the problem is that all 'close' calls in your code no longer are legit close class, but redundant calls, in such a case I don't know if the JDBC is going to throw one more exception (something like 'connection is already closed') or not, but if yes, you need to suppress the exception or something.

But the basic idea here is that you are modifying the sources and that's kind of risky.

Now, even if you find a common fix, the next problem is about the impact, where nobody including you can say the impact of this, and someone else should approve this change (assuming this is large code and is some project).

So, instead of doing things like this, and inviting new issues, it is better to accept the fact that someone in the past did some lousy job and we fix it now the right way.

I know that is exactly what you are trying to avoid here, then I think you should try modifying the JDBC sources and give it a shot. All the best!

Comment: thanks for the important suggestion. I have updated my question with the jdbc implementation details. Modifying source code of an external library and using it in an existing project does sound risky.

Comment: If you see this issue post JAR upgrade, then I think you should first establish whether the issue is with your code or with the library. Many times we end up chasing our own tail otherwise in such cases.

Comment: You can try one more thing though. It'd be hardly couple of interfaces that you'd be using in JDBC, like PreparedStatement/ ResultSet etc. My next suggestion would be to subclass vendor implementation classes (assuming they are not final) and call all 'super' implementations in the implementation methods. Standard IDE features would help you do this quickly. Once done, 'replace all' imports in the 'whole project' to use the sub classes now implemented by you. Now in this, start monkeying around.

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks so much for the continued help. I am however not able to identify the vendor classes. I am using the ojdbc implementation, but in my workspace, references are with the connection interface. Also, theconnection object returned is a dynamic proxy object - com.sun.proxy.$Proxy. That is why I am not able to extend the vendor.

Comment: Yes, Stupid me, I should have realized it. It is better to implement the way @user506069 said in the comment for your question! That's the best way I can think of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're **just** trying to find leaks, why not use a debugger instead? You can set breakpoints on each of the relevant methods and look at where they're called, then step forward to make sure they're closed properly. As an extra benefit, if there are any edge cases that prevent proper closure, you'll have just been stepping through the relevant code, so you can figure out what needs to be fixed much more quickly.