# Spring boot connect with existing JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection

Spring boot provided it's own database connection according to configuration in application.properties. But here I have a service which provided me an object of javax.sql.Connection type.

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Here is code for repository

```
package com.example.springbootdemo.repositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.springbootdemo.model.Box;
public interface BoxRepository extends CrudRepository<Box, Long> {
}
```

Code for controller

```
package com.example.springbootdemo.controllers;

import com.example.springbootdemo.model.Box;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.springbootdemo.repositories.BoxRepository;

@RestController
public class BoxController {

@Autowired
BoxRepository boxrepository;

@PostMapping("/box")
public Box addBox(Box box){
    return this.boxrepository.save(box);
}
}
```

Here when I am calling save function of JPA repository it saves the object using db object which it is calculating by using some of its own wrapper.

But I have to use a jar which gives me Database connection. Instead of configuration in src/main/resources/application.properties, I have to use connection object returned from this jar. Now I'll need to override the connection object that spring boot is using internally. I am not able to figure out how I can do this.

Comment: Just read the Spring-Boot manual.

Comment: @Zorglube I tried to figure this out by reading manual, how do I set up a connection this only I am able to find there but how do I use an existing connection ?

Comment: refer this for clarity of approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796562/how-to-override-some-of-java-sql-connection-methods-like-preparestatement-create.

Comment: In you configuration file you must refer to an JNDI provided connection instead of creating one.

Answer (score 1):

you have this path : src//main//resoruces//application.properties

and here you need to configure

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention what are the properties to configure.

Comment: I have updated my question, I am able to do it with src//main//resoruces//application.properties, but i want to use an existing JDBC connection instead of creating an new one.

Comment: In you configuration file you must refer to an JNDI provided connection instead of creating one.